# finding the directional derivative at the origin

Tags: derivatives, vectors

A certain scalar quantity is governed by the equation $\Phi(x, y, z) = x+y+z^2$. Evaluate the gradient of $\Phi$ along the direction of the
vector, $x{\bf\hat  i} + y{\bf\hat  j} + z{\bf\hat  k}$. Now, evaluate the value of the directional derivative you obtained at the origin of the coordinate system.

I know how to solve the question, but I am not sure of the answer as I am getting it in terms of $0/0$.

edit 1:
[the method/the way i did it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8woo.jpg)

Comment: It would help if you show your solution and how you got your answer.

Comment: Add to question your steps and result obtained when you "solved the question". Then someone can help better.

Comment: @Nick I have added an image of the result that i obtained. do check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion is that you are mixing up $(x,y,z)$ the coordinates of an arbitrary point (which you later set to the origin) and $(x,y,z)$ the vector with respect to which you are taking the directional derivative. Not entirely your fault, as the notation in the question is ripe to such misunderstandings. I will set the direction we are taking the derivative in as $(a,b,c)$, to make things clearer.

---

$\nabla\Phi=(1,1,2z)$, so the directional derivative for the vector $\mathbf n=(a,b,c)$ is $$\mathbf n\cdot\nabla\Phi=\frac{a+b+2cz}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.$$ Now evaluate this at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: I didn't think of it in this way. Thank you! :)